# How can i bind multiple javascript object instance to elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a JavaScript player, but not sure how can i have multiple instance of it in the same page such that each have its on functionality

```js
$(function() {
  var player = function(obj) {
    player.item = obj;
    player.audio = player.item.attr('data-player-src');
    player.audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    player.audioElement.setAttribute('src', player.audio);
    player.audioElement.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
      player.item.find('.length').text('duration : ' + player.audioElement.duration + ' seconds');
    });
    player.audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      player.item.find('.duration').text('current seconds : ' + player.audioElement.currentTime);
    });
    player.item.find('.play').on('click', function() {
      player.play();
    });
    player.item.find('.pause').on('click', function() {
      player.pause();
    });
    player.play = function() {
      player.audioElement.play();
    }
    player.pause = function() {
      player.audioElement.pause();
    }
    return player;
  }

  $.fn.player = function(options) {
    return player($(this));
  }

  var playerone = $("#player1").player();
  var playerone = $("#player2").player();
});
```

```css
.player {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player" id="player1" data-player-src="http://www.soundjay.com/misc/sounds/bell-ringing-01.mp3">
  <div class="length">Length</div>
  <div class="duration"></div>
  <input type="button" class="play" value="Play" />
  <input type="button" class="pause" value="Pause" />
</div>

<div class="player" id="player2" data-player-src="https://www.soundjay.com/free-music/sounds/midnight-ride-01a.mp3">
  <div class="length">Length</div>
  <div class="duration"></div>
  <input type="button" class="play" value="Play" />
  <input type="button" class="pause" value="Pause" />
</div>
```

Currently the button clicks on player1 will trigger player2 or vice versa.
How can i make each player independent on each other in the same page

Comment: In jQuery, the easiest way to do that is by creating a plugin. Without jQuery you'd have to use the `new` keyword to create instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
$(function() {
  var player = function(obj) {
    var player={};//this line
```

into the first line of your function to make it reusable. To make it usable through jquery you can do:

```
$.fn.player=function(options){
  return player($(this));
}
```

Usecase

```
var playerone= $("#el").player();
```

Comment: This results in to same scenario, only the last player functional all

Comment: @psb i dont think so... Put it behind the var player=function(){

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, jut updated the question with the snippet. both player is supposed to play different sound. but seem acting on the same object. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that, how can i achieve the same with using a css class instead of id?
instead of #player i want to use .class such that it will be easy to reuse.

Comment: @Psb you need a tutorial on writing proper jQuery plugins

Comment: @psb no! Dont edit the question. Its not a question anymore. Also, this is a new question